# Zxing Barcode Scanner triggers OnSleep() - OnResume() Methods on start and on finish

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms app. I have a button which triggers the Scanner.

```
<Button VerticalOptions="Center"
        IsVisible="False"
        Text="Scan"
        CornerRadius="10"
        FontSize="Medium"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        TextColor="White"
        Clicked="Scan"
        x:Name="btnScan"/>
```

My scanning function is:

```
private async void Scan(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PermissionStatus granted = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
        if (granted != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            _ = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
        }
        if (granted == PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            try
            {
                MobileBarcodeScanningOptions optionsCustom = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();

                scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
                scanner.TopText = "Insert";
                scanner.BottomText = "Align red line with Barcode";

                optionsCustom.DelayBetweenContinuousScans = 3000;
                scanner.ScanContinuously(optionsCustom, ScanResult);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                scanner.Cancel();
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Problem", "Something went wrong.", "ΟΚ");
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is after the scanner is actually opened, the OnSleep() method in App.xaml.cs is triggered.

```
protected override void OnSleep()
{
        
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
        
}
```

And after the scanner is closed the OnResume() method is triggered.

Is this behavior expected? Am i doing something wrong with the scanner initialization?

Comment: _"Is this behavior expected?"_ - Well, _I_ would expect that, since it switches from your App to another App and back...

Comment: That makes sense. Any suggestion on how to "ignore" the OnSleep and OnResume if they are triggered by the scanner? @Fildor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, your question then becomes not to suppress the behaviour you're seeing but handle it. So you could put a static flag in the App class so you know the scanner is active and put your handler code inside this.

App.xaml.cs:

```
public static bool ScannerActive { get; set; }

protected override void OnSleep()
{
    if (!ScannerActive)
    {
        HandleOnSleep();
    }
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    if (!ScannerActive)
    {
        HandleOnResume();
    }

    // Reset the flag if we are coming back from the scanner
    else App.ScannerActive = false;
}
```

Scanning function:

```
private async void Scan(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.ScannerActive = true;

    try
    {
        // ... //
        scanner.ScanContinuously(optionsCustom, ScanResult);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Reset flag if it crashed out
        App.ScannerActive = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing a handler but the problem with this approach is that the `scanner.ScanContinuously(optionsCustom, ScanResult);` doesn't actually open the scanner immediately. After all code is executed in Scan method then the scanner opens. So `App.ScannerActive = false;` would execute before the scanner actually opens. Thank you for the answer. @CodingLumis

Comment: OK what about setting the flag in your `ScanResult` method?

Comment: ScanResult will trigger only if i scan something. Which means that OnSleep() is already triggered. @CodingLumis

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the problem here but the sequence of events you want is: Scan function called -> switch off handling -> initiateScanning -> OnSleep called -> scan captured / exited -> onResume called -> turn handling back on. Correct?

Comment: Practiacally i need to know if the OnSleep() is triggered by my scanner or not. So Press scanner button -> Raise flag -> Initiate Scanning -> OnSleep() called -> Do nothing because flag is raised -> Exit Scanning -> OnResume() called -> Do nothing because flag is raised -> Lower flag.. So the actual problem is how to know if my OnResume() is triggered by scanner or not, since i can't know when my scanner closed and lower my flag.

Comment: Sounds to me that if OnResume is fired every time you come back from the scanner then all you need to check for is whether the flag is set when you come back in and re-enabled it. I've updated my answer -- does that work for you?

Comment: Yes. With some minor modifications to fit the rest of my code it works like this. Thank you for your time.